# Using DataFrame.query() with pandas.Series.str.contains gets AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created two query strings using `str.contains()`, and combine them, then pass it to `DataFrame.query()`.

> I get an AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'.

Removing `regex=False` parameter worked fine but my data contains some `'/*'`. 
So I need this parameter to treat my data as a literal string.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['osaka', ], 'food': ['apple', ],})

querystr1 = 'osaka'
querystr2 = 'apple'

querystr1 = "city.str.contains('" + querystr1 + "', regex=False)"
querystr2 = "food.str.contains('" + querystr2 + "', regex=False)"
querystr = querystr1 + ' & ' + querystr2
print(querystr)

value = df.query(querystr, engine='python').index.values.astype(int)

print(value)
print(value.size)
```

How can I query my dataframe not recognizing regular expressions?
Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but removing the `regex=False` part worked for me:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['osaka', ], 'food': ['apple', ],})

querystr1 = 'osaka'
querystr2 = 'apple'

querystr1 = "city.str.contains('" + querystr1 + "')"
querystr2 = "food.str.contains('" + querystr2 + "')"
querystr = querystr1 + ' & ' + querystr2
print(querystr)

value = df.query(querystr, engine='python').index.values.astype(int)
```